# Installation Length

Tags: system-installation

Okay, so I've been waiting for Ubuntu 13.04 to install on my computer for about an hour. At first, it had the bar at the top and the desktop shown with a spinning cursor. Now the bar has disappeared, and all I have is the spinning cursor. Should it really be taking this time? I did check to install flash and all that, but I didn't check for it to update.

Edit: Nevermind. It finished.

Answer (score 3):

## The Short Answer:

Generally... 25 minutes to an hour. I never really timed it, though.

## The Long Answer:

CD read speeds may vary by manufacturer, but are usually very slow across the board. The only reason CDs are still used today (IMHO) are as a legacy format (they've been around for a LOOOONG time,)  and also they're cheap to produce en  masse. (A stack of 50 700MB CD's? 20 bucks. A decent 8 GB flash drive usually runs you about $18.)

You're much better off using a USB stick if speed is a concern.

---

If you want to try a USB stick, you have a few options:

- [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)

This is a very basic live USB creator, it's pretty reliable and works for most Linux distros, except GParted Live and something else.

- [Pendrivelinux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/)

Another tried-and-true USB creator, this one lets you create a bootable USB stick from an ISO.

- The Method Of Eternal Epicness *(for lack of a better name ;)*

This one is my favorite, I actually figured it out while messing around with `dd`, but the basic idea is that you "burn" the ISO to the USB stick directly, without bothering with live usb creators or any of that.
On Linux, if your USB drive was the first flash drive you plugged in, you can run:

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb*
sudo dd if=/path/to/the/iso/you/downloaded/filename.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

On Windows, you can use [RawWrite](http://www.chrysocome.net/rawwrite) to write the ISO to the USB stick.

Comment: Aw, poop. I spent 20 minutes typing up and wordsmithing that answer, and when I finally posted it, I saw.... the edit you made. I hope you found my answer educational anyway! :)